# "Accounts for last year" or "Accounts of last year"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> The accounts for last year showed a profit of $2 million.

or

> The accounts of last year showed a profit of $2 million.

Which one is correct? My idea is that both of them is OK, anybody can confirm it?

Comment: Both seem appropriate for conversational English. I'd use "for" in writing if I had to choose between the two. Also try _Last year's accounts showed..._

Comment: I would probably go for the former if for no other reasons than "accounts of" can also mean "stories regarding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Accounts for last year" seems more common in financial reports I've read, and also, as Sean Duggan says, avoids possible misunderstanding of the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the context would be sufficient to avoid any ambiguity, so either is probably alright. According to [google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accounts%20of%20last%20year,accounts%20for%20last%20year,last%20year%27s%20accounts&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the two phrases occur with similar frequency. However, 'last year's accounts' is far more common than either.